# Tool for NFA/DFA manipulation

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I am look for a tool with any or all of the following features:

1. Regular Expresstion to NFA converter that represents transitions as Binary Decision Diagrams
2. NFA to DFA converter
3. NFA minimization
4. NFA union/complement/intersection

Can you recommend one?

Comment: @D.W. Actually, in case of scientific software, the last consensus on meta.cs seems to be that this question was actually OK (if the "widely used" is dropped from the question): https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87756/popular-tool-for-nfa-dfa-manipulation

Comment: @DCTLib, OK, I've re-opened it.   Thank you!  (I'm guessing you meant to link to https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/660/755 or https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/473/755.)  However, requests for "your favorite [anything]" are not suitable here (it's one of the bullet items in our [help/dont-ask]), so I've edited this to focus on the specific requirements identified by the poster.

Comment: I agree; this should be closed as "opinion based" or "offtopic". Without criteria what makes a tool suitable, we have an open-ended list question here, full of non-CS answers. (cc @D.W. )